# Accessing value types that are automatically generated from properties

Tags: c#, properties

Most examples when talking about automatically generated properties talk about "simple" value types such as strings. But what if you'd like to access a field of such a value type that is generated automatically in the IL to back up an "automatic property"?

The compiler won't allow to do this: "Cannot modify the return value of 'Position' because it is not a variable". I understand why we cannot modify this return value, but how would we then access these fields?

Say we have

```
class A
{
    Vector2 Position { get; set; }

    public void Foo()
    {
        Position.X = 10.0f;    // Not allowed!
    }
}
```

How do I access and set the field X of the Vector2 instance within class A?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Accessing **reference types** that are automatically generated from properties

Your problem is that `Vector2` is *not* a reference type; it is a value type.  When you access the property `Position` a copy is returned, so you are attempting to mutate a temporary.  In this situation you need to set a completely new value:

```
Position = new Vector2(10.0, Position.Y);
```

You could also create a private field in this case and not use an automatic property:

```
class A
{
    Vector2 _position;
    Vector2 Position 
    { 
        get { return _position; } 
        set { _position = value; }
    }

    public void Foo()
    {
        _position.X = 10.0f;  
    }
}
```

Documentation: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.vector2.aspx

Comment: Thanks. So, just because Vector2 happens to be a value type, we can't use properties this way because a copy gets returned by the generated Getter. I think in this case it would be better to have the backing underlying variable available, so we don't have to deal with properties differently just because we're using value types...

Comment: @user1610325: Of course, users of your code don't have that luxury.  It's ok though as they will know exactly what is going on.  The framework itself defines types which have value type properties (for example, `Form.Location`).  On a side note... I totally answered this first, you should have chosen mine :D

Comment: Sorry, didn't quite catch the check-thingy yet :-). In your opinion, would you introduce the _position variable solution, which allows to directly manipulate fields, or would you just create whole new Vector2 instances? I guess new'ing value types on the stack shouldn't be too much of an overhead in this case? (I'm a Java/C++ developer migrating to C#)

Comment: @user1610325: Regarding this: *" I guess new'ing value types on the stack"* - those are not necessarily stack allocated (and, in practice, certainly will not be) because they are a part of the parent object.  It is likely a premature optimization regardless, but you would be well served to read up on the semantics of value types v reference types (it is not as simple as "stack v heap").  Also, [this is a good read](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/04/27/the-stack-is-an-implementation-detail.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

Vector2 is actually a value type, not a reference type. You'll have to create a new Vector2:

```
Postion = new Vector2(10.0f, Position.Y);
```